# Are these two length scales in FH exhaust plumes real, understood, and distinct?

Tags: falcon-9, falcon-heavy, merlin-1d, exhaust

The Ars Technica article [We can admit it—we’re dazzled by the controlled fury of the Falcon Heavy](https://arstechnica.com/science/2019/04/for-a-moment-appreciate-falcon-heavys-controlled-explosion-of-four-tons-of-tnt/) includes a beautiful photo of the exhaust plume produced by the 27 engines of a Falcon Heavy launch.

I think I can see two different characteristic length scales.

**The first is a radial effect with a length scale of about 3 meters**, shown in the first image, when the expanding exhaust with subatmospheric pressure is compressed by the surrounding atmosphere and gets slightly compressed from the sides.

**The second is a longitudinal effect with a length scale of about 8 meters** and might be similar or related to the periodic appearance of shock diamonds in some other exhaust plumes.

**Question:** Are these two length scales real, understood, and distinct?

**update:** I've adjusted the annotation of the 2nd image to make it clearer how small the length scale in the first image is when viewed in the second image.

[image: Falcon Heavy length scales of longitudinal oscillations in exhaust plume]

[image: Falcon Heavy length scales of longitudinal oscillations in exhaust plume]

---

This [tweeted image](https://twitter.com/TheFavoritist/status/1109904095182237696) of exhaust plumes from the nine Rutherford engines of an Electron rocket (smaller but similar-Isp RP-1 LOX engines) is shown for contrast. It is dominated by clearly periodic longitudinal oscillation with a single length scale.

[image]

Comment: My turbulent jet answer to another question got no love so I won't bring it up here. Even though that is what it is.

Comment: The first “element”, the expansion-contraction, properly starts at the engine throat, not the nozzle exit plane. On that basis I would guess the two phenomena are of the same scale and tightly correlated.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've added the two little arrows in the 2nd image to better show the difference that (at least) I am seeing.

Comment: The phenomenon seen in the second image must be Mach diamonds. Can't think of any other explanation.